# Display:none and DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

if `display: none` removes element from the DOM, why I am able to see it in dev-tools inspector or access via `document.getElementBy`? It should be somehow one way road. If we removes element via `display: none`, it should not be present anywhere. How should I understand "removing from DOM"?

Comment: it is removed from the visual representation of the DOM

Comment: It doesn't. (If you were reading some site or blog that said it did, and if it really said that, it's incorrect.) `display: none` makes the element **not displayed**. It's still in the DOM tree. It's just not visible.

Answer (score 4):

> if display: none removes element from the DOM

It doesn't. It causes it to render as if it were not in the DOM.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display):

> Turns off the display of an element so that it has no effect on layout (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist). All descendant elements also have their display turned off.

Comment: ok thanks, a lot of websites tells something like 'its removed from DOM' what I see is not true.

Answer (score 1):

If you *actually* want to remove an element from the DOM, you can use **Javascript**:

```
myElementParent.removeChild(myElement);
```

or:

```
myElement.remove();
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

---

But, in **CSS**, the following property-value pairs:

- `display: none;`
- `visibility: hidden;`
- `opacity: 0; pointer-events: none;`

all represent approaches to remove *visibility* and *interactivity* from an element which **remains in the DOM**.

The key difference between the first of these and the latter two is that `display: none;` ***also*** removes the space that would otherwise be occupied by the element.

Answer (score 1):

`display:none` does ***not*** remove the element from the DOM, it only hides the element but it will still be there

you need to use the `remove` method in javascript like this `yourElement.remove();` to actually remove it from the DOM